# C++ Eigen 32 bit and 64 bit Error

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a C++ image processing application using Eigen. I am working in VS 2013. I have the code working error free when running on 64 bit, however, when running it on 32 bit I encounter an:

> Access Code Violation

The image is described by the Eigen Array

```
template<typename Pixel>
using Image = Eigen::Array < Pixel, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor > ;
```

When the variable `bayer`is assigned type `Image` then the 64 bit version looks like this:

[image]

However the 32 bit version looks like this:

[image]

When data is passed into `bayer` then the 64 bit looks like this:

[image]

It has a clear element structure with values, whereas the 32 bit version is more complex and I think it is creating problems further down in the code.

[image]

I am not sure whether the difference in format is leading to my eventual error, or whether it is something else, but this is the only difference I have noticed, so thought I would ask the question.

Comment: The difference in the representation of the debugger is just the visualizer. See [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Developer%27s_Corner#Debugging_under_Visual_Studio). That's not the source of your problems. Try looking elsewhere and create a [MCVE].

Comment: @AviGinsburg - I am not sure what the link tells me? Are you sure it is just differences in Visualizer?  I agree with the MCVE approach, but this is a huge project and right now I am not sure how to break it down.

Comment: Yes, the difference is just the visualizer. `bater.m_storage.m_data` will give you the pointer to the data array, just without the indices.